# Homogeneity and Differentiability at $0$ implies linearity?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, linear-algebra

Suppose $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ is homogeneous and differentiable at $0$, then does it follow that $f$ is a linear transformation?

I know that I need to show that for any $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$, then

$$ f( \lambda x + y ) = \lambda f(x) + f(y) $$.

I know by homogeneity that $f( \lambda x ) = \lambda f(x) $. But how can I show that $f$ preserves the operation $+$ ?

Comment: This question has two answers, both of them answer it quite well. Can you at least explain what bothers you about the answers, if you are puting a bounty on it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since $f$ is differentiable at $0$, it has the form $$f(x) = f(0) +  D_f(0) x + o(x)$$
where $D_f(0)$ is a matrix and $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{o(x)}{||x||} = 0$. Choosing $\lambda = 0$ in $f(\lambda x) = \lambda f(x)$ quickly gives you $f(0)=0$, so $f$ has the form 
$$f(x) = D_f(0) x + o(x).$$
Now, replace $x$ with $\lambda x$ and you get

$$\lambda f(x) = \lambda D_f(0)x + o(\lambda x)$$
or $$o(\lambda x) = \lambda(f(x) - D_f(0) x) = \lambda o(x).$$

Now take any $0\neq x\in\mathbb R^n$. You then have
$$0=\lim_{\lambda \downarrow 0}\frac{o(\lambda x)}{||\lambda x||}=\lim_{\lambda\downarrow 0}\frac{o(x)}{||x||} = \frac{o(x)}{||x||}.$$

This means $o(x) = 0$ for all $x$, meaning $f$ has the form $f(x) = D_f(0) x$ and $f$ is linear.

Answer (score 2):

Obviously we have $f(0)=0$. Since $f$ is differentiable at $0$ we have
$$
df_0(h)=\lim_{t\to0}\frac{f(0+th)-f(0)}{t}=\lim_{t\to0}\frac{f(th)}{t}=f(h) \quad \forall h \in \mathbb{R}^n.
$$
Since $df_0$ is linear so is $f$.

Comment: Why $df_0$ linear implies $f$ is linear ?

Comment: Because $df_0=f$.

Comment: Can you please explain your notation? What $df_0(h)$ stands for? I am extremely confused.